# How to resolve System.Unauthorized access exception?

Tags: c#, exception

I have add updater for an application (Myapp.exe). When I launch **Myapp.exe** then it checks the new available version and download it according to users instruction into **Windows Temp directory**. After downloading the update to Temp directory, the new program **replacer.exe** runs which is responsible to get **Myapp.exe**, kill its process, delete **Myapp.exe** and copy new version (of Myapp.exe) from Temp directory to Myapp.exe old path. The **replacer.exe** has following code.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {                       
                Process myProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("Myapp")[0];    
                myProcess.Kill();
                File.Delete(args[0]);
                File.Copy(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + "\\Temp\\Myapp.exe", args[0], false);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write(e.ToString() + "");
                //return;
            }               
            //Console.Write( "Success");
            try
            {
                Process.Start(args[0]);
            }
            catch (Exception es) 
            {
                Console.Write(es.ToString() + "");
                //return;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

But replacer.exe unable to delete Myapp.exe and give exception **System.UnauthorizedAccessException**. Thats mean the replacer.exe cannot access the path given by Myapp.exe while deleting Myapp.exe
Note: I have run UserAccount, Myapp.exe and replacer.exe as Administrator and Normal user as well.
How can I resolve it. Please help me.
Thanks in advance. . .

Comment: There is no problem in args[0] contents and Myapp.exe is not read only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes a little while for a process to end: `Process.Kill()` merely *tells* the process to stop, but doesn't want for it to actually finish.

You'll want to introduce a loop with a short delay and a check to see if the process has actually terminated.

Use the property `Process.HasExited` to check this: documentation on MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually checked the contents of `args[0]`? `File.Delete` doesn't just throw an `UnauthorizedAccessException` if it lacks the necessary permissions; it can also be thrown if the path leads to a directory or a read-only file.